# number formatting

Tags: jython, numbers

I have a simple question how can i show the number  12045678 as 12,045,678  i.e automatically  show in american format in jython

so 12345 should be 12,345  and 1234567890 should be 1,234,567,890 and so on.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Added vote to close because it's a duplicate of the question I left a link to in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-python-2-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How to print number with commas as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-python-2-x)

Answer (score 1):

See [the official documentation](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/string.html), in particular **7.1.3.1. Format Specification Mini-Language** and in particular:

> `'n'  Number.` This is the same as 'g',
>   except that it uses the current locale
>   setting to insert the appropriate
>   number separator characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
def numberToPrettyString(n):
   """Converts a number to a nicely formatted string.
      Example: 6874 => '6,874'."""
   l = []
   for i, c in enumerate(str(n)[::-1]):
       if i%3==0 and i!=0:
           l += ','
       l += c
   return "".join(l[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

prior to 2.6 there is no built-in function

this is the easiest one I've found

```
def splitthousands(s, sep=','):  
    if len(s) <= 3: return s  
    return splitthousands(s[:-3], sep) + sep + s[-3:]
```

splitthousands('123456')

123,456