# How to "comma" format the output of a django variable?

Tags: python, django

I have this variable:

```
{{ object.article.rating.get_percent|floatformat }}
```

that outputs this:

```
540787
```

Is there a way to format it so it shows as:

```
540,787
```

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-python-2-x

Comment: @tMC no I was hoping to do it from a template level. I don't have access to the python code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this should help you out:
http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2010/02/django-formatting-numbers-with-commas.html

details:
add "django.contrib.humanize" to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.

then in the template:

```
{% load humanize %}
{{ price|intcomma }}
```