# how to format phone number according to international caller id space state caller id and phone number in python using regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have one phone number "+9779841915591" and for this number I want to arrange into international caller id space state id space and phone using regex.

Comment: I want in this format: +977 9841 915591

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to format a phone number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058120/whats-the-best-way-to-format-a-phone-number-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for your link. I got that answer but now I have list :list =["1234567890", "+9779841915591", "2375952486"], Here I want to clean phone number by replacing first three number by country code how can I clean this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna just leave this here

```
 phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'+\d\d\d \d\d\d\d \d\d\d\d\d\d')
```

More info: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter7/