# How to make python tkinter automatically add slashes after every 2 characters

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
def e_input():
    print(e1.get())
l1=Label(root,text="Enter here:")
l1.place(x=30,y=40)
e1=Entry(root,bd=2,width=25)
e1.place(x=100,y=40)
b1=Button(root,text="Enter",command=e_input)
b1.place(x=250,y=40)
root.mainloop()
```

In this code, the user manually has to enter the slashes after every 2 characters.
help me out to make that thing by default,
Image attached as to how I needed it to be...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Uba.png)

Comment: The image you show doesn't have slashes after _every_ two characters. It only has a slash after the first two and then the next two characters.

Comment: I am sorry, actually, I was planning to take input from the user for hours minutes, and second, in that context, I wrote that I needed python to automatically put slashes after every 2 characters.

Comment: but, you get the point I needed python to automatically put slashes after every two characters

Comment: Ok, so you do not want what the picture shows. Instead, you want `21/04/20/20`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Bryanoakley is there a way to do it, while the user types in the entry itself? I had asked a Q before and got no proper answers

Comment: @BryanOakley Correct!!

Comment: actually original it was supposed to be 14:04:02 but I don't know how did I lose my track.
and Now it became 21/04/20/20

Comment: this is a small project wherein we are supposed to take in input from the user for the time but with the automatic colon being the respectively places

Comment: What it you take the input and press a button and then after that colon gets added on? i asked a similar Q [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62119551/auto-add-dashes-to-entryboxes-in-tkinter) but didnt get any proper answer out

Comment: Really a good question

Comment: an idea sparked in my head what if we use for loop(inside a while loop, label.bind('<FocusIn>'), and after every 2 characters a colon is given to the str.

I am not sure will this work or not, just thought of it.

Comment: sorry entry.bind not label.bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example we expand the `Entry` widget to handle your date format. The `validatecommand` makes sure that we are entering numbers and that the text matches the format of the `regular expression`. The key `bind` handles inserting slashes in the proper position.

```
import tkinter as tk, re

class DateEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Entry.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        vcmd = self.register(self.validate)
        
        self.bind('<Key>', self.format)
        self.configure(validate="all", validatecommand=(vcmd, '%P'))
        
        self.valid = re.compile('^\d{0,2}(\\\\\d{0,2}(\\\\\d{0,4})?)?$', re.I)
             
    def validate(self, text):
        if ''.join(text.split('\\')).isnumeric():
            return not self.valid.match(text) is None
        return False
    
    def format(self, event):
        if event.keysym != 'BackSpace':
            i = self.index('insert')
            if i in [2, 5]:
                if self.get()[i:i+1] != '\\':
                    self.insert(i, '\\')
        

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        DateEntry(self, width=10).grid(row=0, column=0)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Main()
    root.geometry('800x600')
    root.title("Date Entry Example")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, Mate,
your code did work, I am very new to python recently I learned about classes and this (tkinter module). This will work perfectly for the day/month/year, but what if I needed to change it to time (for example 14:20:04) how should I change it

Comment: @Hafeezh ~ Ask a time question and I will answer it

Comment: self.valid = re.compile('^\d{0,2}(\\\\\d{0,2}(\\\\\d{0,4})?)?$', re.I) , this few codes of line went above my head, would surly google it out!!

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63622880/how-to-make-python-automaticlly-put-colon-in-the-format-of-time-hhmmss)

Comment: Hey @MichaelGuidry can you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62119551/auto-add-dashes-to-entryboxes-in-tkinter) and maybe suggest a similar solution there?im not into OOP much though