# How to make python automatically put colon in the format of time (HH:MM:SS)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
def t_input():
    print(e1.get())
l1=Label(root,text="Enter here your time:")
l1.place(x=20,y=50)
e1=Entry(root,bd=2,width=25)
e1.place(x=90,y=50)
b1=Button(root,text="Enter",command=t_input)
b1.place(x=240,y=50)
root.mainloop()
```

This is my code, the user has to input a colon after hour, minute, seconds

Please help me in making it by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my example we extend the `Entry` widget to handle your time format. The `validatecommand` makes sure we are inputting numbers, and that the text matches the `regular expression`. The key `bind` handles insertion of colon.

```
import tkinter as tk, re

class TimeEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Entry.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        vcmd = self.register(self.validate)

        self.bind('<Key>', self.format)
        self.configure(validate="all", validatecommand=(vcmd, '%P'))

        self.valid = re.compile('^\d{0,2}(:\d{0,2}(:\d{0,2})?)?$', re.I)

    def validate(self, text):
        if ''.join(text.split(':')).isnumeric():
            return not self.valid.match(text) is None
        return False

    def format(self, event):
        if event.keysym != 'BackSpace':
            i = self.index('insert')
            if i in [2, 5]:
                if self.get()[i:i+1] != ':':
                    self.insert(i, ':')


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        TimeEntry(self, width=8).grid(row=0, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Main()
    root.geometry('800x600')
    root.title("Time Entry Example")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you recommend me some documentation or somethings where in tkinter module is explained

Comment: because I am very new to python programming

Comment: @Hafeezh ~ I use https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ for quick info.  I also use https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html. Care to accept my answer?

Comment: thanks for the documentation, and I have accepted your answer.