# Adding placeholders to tkinter Entry widget in a procedural way

Tags: python, tkinter, placeholder

I know this Q has been answered in this site, but im looking for a more simpler answer, and ive seen one before but then the question has been deleted or something, I cant find it. Hopefully someone is having a better and easier way around to it. Something related to class might be better as I could use it easily with more `Entry` widgets

Here is a snippet:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def remove(event):
    e.delete(0, END)

e = Entry(root)
e.insert(0, 'PLACEHOLDER')
e.pack(padx=100,pady=(30,0))
e.bind('<FocusIn>', remove)

e2 = Entry(root)
e2.pack( pady=(20,100))

root.mainloop()
```

Yes, this will remove all the other items inside of the box once it looses focus and gains it again, including the text we enter at first. Anyway to get around that and have a perfect placeholder with tkinter, I'm aware there is no inbuilt way.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: You seem to already have code that works. It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @bryanoakley _"this will remove all the other items inside of the box once it looses focus and gains it again, including the text we enter at first_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple example. In this example we include a couple of features/caveats:

- ghost text for the placeholder
- `entry.input` will return `None` if it's text is the placeholder or empty
- `entry.input` should be used in place of `.get()` and `.insert()`. The `.input` logic is designed to give you the proper results for this type of widget. `.get()` is not smart enough to return the proper data, and `.insert()` has been reconfigured as a proxy to `.input`
- placeholder is juggled while you type
- placeholder can be overwritten with `.insert()` ~ no need to use `.delete()`. You should still use `entry.input` instead

---

```
#widgets.py

import tkinter as tk

class PlaceholderEntry(tk.Entry):
    '''
        All Of These Properties Are For Convenience
    '''
    @property
    def input(self):
        return self.get() if self.get() not in [self.__ph, ''] else None
        
    @input.setter
    def input(self, value):
        self.delete(0, 'end')
        self.insert(0, value)
        self.configure(fg = self.ghost if value == self.__ph else self.normal)
    
    @property
    def isempty(self) -> bool:
        return self.get() == ''
    
    @property     
    def isholder(self) -> bool:
        return self.get() == self.__ph
        
    def __init__(self, master, placeholder, **kwargs):
        tk.Entry.__init__(self, master, **{'disabledforeground':'#BBBBBB', **kwargs})
        
        self.normal = self['foreground']
        self.ghost  = self['disabledforeground']
        
        self.__ph = placeholder
        self.input = placeholder
        
        vcmd = self.register(self.validate)
        self.configure(validate='all', validatecommand=(vcmd, '%S', '%s', '%d'))
        
        self.bind('<FocusIn>' , self.focusin)
        self.bind('<FocusOut>', self.focusout)
        self.bind('<Key>'     , self.check)
    
    #rewire .insert() to be a proxy of .input
    def validate(self, action_text, orig_text, action):
        if action == '1':
            if orig_text == self.__ph:
                self.input = action_text
            
        return True
    
    #removes placeholder if necessary    
    def focusin(self, event=None):
        if self.isholder:
            self.input = ''
    
    #adds placeholder if necessary    
    def focusout(self, event=None):
        if self.isempty:
            self.input = self.__ph
    
    #juggles the placeholder while you type    
    def check(self, event):
        if event.keysym == 'BackSpace':
            if self.input and len(self.input) == 1:
                self.input = self.__ph
                self.icursor(0)
                return 'break'
        elif self.isholder:
            if event.char:
                self.input = ''
            else:
                return 'break'
```

---

usage example:

```
#__main__.py

import tkinter as tk
import widgets as ctk #custom tk                
                

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Placeholder Entry")
    root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    #init some data
    entries    = [] #for storing entry references
    label_text = ['email', 'name']
    entry_text = ['you@mail.com', 'John Smith']

    #create form
    for n, (label, placeholder) in enumerate(zip(label_text, entry_text)):
        #make label
        tk.Label(root, text=f'{label}: ', width=8, font='consolas 12 bold', anchor='w').grid(row=n, column=0, sticky='w')
        #make entry
        entries.append(ctk.PlaceholderEntry(root, placeholder, width=14, font='consolas 12 bold'))
        entries[-1].grid(row=n, column=1, sticky='w')

    #form submit function
    def submit():
        for l, e in zip(label_text, entries):
            if e.input:
                print(f'{l}: {e.input}')

    #form submit button        
    tk.Button(root, text='submit', command=submit).grid(column=1, sticky='e')

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you put the first function on to a class on a seperate file, so i can import it like the `ctk` from widgets ?

Comment: and also is there a way to show the placeholder while the the focus is on the widget and the entry widget is empty. like when we backspace all the characters and the field is empty, without moving the focus we could get placeholder text displayed

Comment: @CoolCloud ~ I had to fix one mistake. I accidentally had `self.bind('<FocusOut>', self.focusin)`. It's fixed

Comment: Oh, no issues, its fine!!

Comment: But if the box is empty, and then using the `get()` will give me the placeholder and how to use the `inset()` and `delete()` effectively? it seems to effect the placeholder inplace

Comment: @CoolCloud - don't use `get()`, use `.input`. My usage example is there so you can see how to manage the widget. `get()` is no good for this type of tech. What if the user doesn't fill out the form, at all? Using `get()` you are going to have a lot of users with placholder account info. `.input` removes this problem.

Comment: Oh okays, got it, what about `inset()` and `delete()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220709/discussion-between-michael-guidry-and-cool-cloud).

Comment: The `PlaceholderEntry` has all of the same methods as a regular `Entry` (even `get`), `.input` is in addition to the default possibilities.

Comment: @CoolCloud ~ just an FYI, you could have simply used `entry.input = 'whatever'` and skipped `.insert()` entirely.  `.input` has a getter and a setter.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really clear on what you're asking, so I'm guessing you're asking how to know when the entry widget has placeholder text and when it doesn't so that you know when to clear it and when not to clear it.

The easiest solution is to add an attribute to the entry with the replacement text, and then compare it to the contents before deleting.

### Using functions

First, let's create a function to initialize the placeholder text for a widget. This function does a few simple things: it adds a `placeholder` attribute on the widget, and it establishes the bindings. It also inserts the placeholder if the widget is empty:

```
def init_placeholder(widget, placeholder_text):
    widget.placeholder = placeholder_text
    if widget.get() == "":
        widget.insert("end", placeholder_text)

    # set up a binding to remove placeholder text
    widget.bind("<FocusIn>", remove_placeholder)
    widget.bind("<FocusOut>", add_placeholder)
```

Now let's tweak your `remove` function to be a bit more generic. Since it's called via an event, it can use `event.widget` rather than a hard-coded reference to a specific widget. It also uses the `placeholder` attribute which we added to the widget. These two techniques lets it be used by more than one widget.

```
def remove_placeholder(event):
    placeholder_text = getattr(event.widget, "placeholder", "")
    if placeholder_text and event.widget.get() == placeholder_text:
        event.widget.delete(0, "end")
```

Finally we need to implement the `add_placeholder` function. This function will add the placeholder when the widget loses focus and the user hasn't typed anything. It needs to check if the entry widget has a placeholder, and if it does and the widget is empty, it adds the placeholder. Like `remove_placeholder` it uses `event.widget` and the `placeholder` attribute:

```
def add_placeholder(event):
    placeholder_text = getattr(event.widget, "placeholder", "")
    if placeholder_text and event.widget.get() == "":
        event.widget.insert(0, placeholder_text)
```

I've modified your program to use different placeholder text for each of the two entry widgets to show that the functions are generic and not tied to a specific entry widget.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def remove_placeholder(event):
    """Remove placeholder text, if present"""
    placeholder_text = getattr(event.widget, "placeholder", "")
    if placeholder_text and event.widget.get() == placeholder_text:
        event.widget.delete(0, "end")

def add_placeholder(event):
    """Add placeholder text if the widget is empty"""
    placeholder_text = getattr(event.widget, "placeholder", "")
    if placeholder_text and event.widget.get() == "":
        event.widget.insert(0, placeholder_text)

def init_placeholder(widget, placeholder_text):
    widget.placeholder = placeholder_text
    if widget.get() == "":
        widget.insert("end", placeholder_text)

    # set up a binding to remove placeholder text
    widget.bind("<FocusIn>", remove_placeholder)
    widget.bind("<FocusOut>", add_placeholder)

e = Entry(root)
e.pack(padx=100,pady=(30,0))

e2 = Entry(root)
e2.pack( pady=(20,100))

init_placeholder(e, "First Name")
init_placeholder(e2, "Last Name")

root.mainloop()
```

### Using a custom class

Arguably, a better way to implement this would be to create a custom class. That way everything is encapsulated in one place. Here's an example:

```
class EntryWithPlaceholder(Entry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.placeholder = kwargs.pop("placeholder", "")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.insert("end", self.placeholder)
        self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.remove_placeholder)
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.add_placeholder)

    def remove_placeholder(self, event):
        """Remove placeholder text, if present"""
        if self.get() == self.placeholder:
            self.delete(0, "end")

    def add_placeholder(self,event):
        """Add placeholder text if the widget is empty"""
        if self.placeholder and self.get() == "":
            self.insert(0, self.placeholder)
```

You can use this class just like an `Entry` widget, but you can specify a placeholder:

```
e3 = EntryWithPlaceholder(root, placeholder="Address")
e3.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def remove(event):
    if e.get() == 'PLACEHOLDER': #Check default value
        e.delete(0, END)

def add(event):
    if not e.get(): #Check if left empty
        e.insert(0, 'PLACEHOLDER')     

e = Entry(root)
e.insert(0, 'PLACEHOLDER')
e.pack(padx=100,pady=(30,0))
e.bind('<FocusIn>', remove)
e.bind('<FocusOut>', add)

e2 = Entry(root)
e2.pack( pady=(20,100))

root.mainloop()
```

By doing this you will be clearing only if the default value is present in the `Text` and also, if the field is left empty, the placeholder gets back into the `Text`.

Comment: What if im typing and I backspaced everything and moved on to the next widget, that would leave the entry empty right without placeholder?

Comment: @CloudCool Not exactly, backspacing everything will make the entry empty, but as soon as you move on to the next widget, the placeholder will be inserted, because the condition only checks if it is empty, it doesn't matter whether you have typed and backspaced.

Comment: You know placeholders work right, when we backspace all the characters and the field is empty, without moving the focus we could get placeholder text displayed,other two answers has that concept in i guess. Thank for this great and simple idea ive missed :D I would definitely use this in small projects

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not directly, possible with `tkinter`. You might want to use classes and OOP.