# Make Tkinter run a command without clicking or pressing a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a simple `tkinter` popup where you can type a message.
In the textbox itself, I inserted the text "Type your message here" with a grey colour and when clicked, the inserted text is deleted so the user can type in their own message. In addition, the colour of the text typed by the user is set to black.

However, when I was testing I realised that this will only happen if they click the textbox with a mouse button.  My question is, is there a way for `tkinter` to automatically run a command when a condition is changed? For example, if the textbox is empty, the font colour should be set to black.
I tried putting if-statements in the `tk.mainloop`, but sadly that didn't work.

Any ideas?

this is my (hopefully) simplified version of the code:

```
from tkinter import *

def changecolor(event):
    if textbox.get("1.0", "end-1c") == "Type your message here":
        textbox.delete("1.0", "end")
        textbox.config(fg='black')

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, height=400, width=600)
canvas.pack()

textbox = Text(canvas, font=40, fg="grey")
textbox.insert(1.0, "Type your message here")
textbox.bind("<Button-1>", changecolor)
textbox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

~finally found out how to format code here.

Comment: What your looking for is called placeholders. There are plenty of Q on this site about placeholders. Take a look at what I made [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250083/python-tkinter-placeholder-class) or you could just search this site for more Q, or even check a Q that I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63651586/adding-placeholders-to-tkinter-entry-widget-in-a-procedural-way) on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this class I created that does similar to what your code does, do try it on.

```
from tkinter import *

class PlaceholderText(Text):
    def __init__(self,master,placeholder,placeholdercolor='black',fg='grey',**kwargs):
        Text.__init__(self,master,**kwargs) #init the text widget
        self.placeholder = placeholder 
        self.fgcolor = fg
        self.placeholdercolor = placeholdercolor
        self.has_placeholder = False #make flag

        self.add() #run the function to add placeholder
        self.bind('<FocusIn>',self.clear) #binding to focusin and not button-1
        self.bind('<FocusOut>',self.add) #function wil get triggered when widget loses focus

    def clear(self,event=None):
        if self.get('1.0','end-1c') == self.placeholder and self.has_placeholder: #condition to clear a placeholder
            self.delete('1.0','end-1c') #delete the placeholder
            self.config(fg=self.fgcolor) #change the color
            self.has_placeholder = False #set flag to flase

    def add(self,event=None):
        if self.get('1.0','end-1c') == '' and not self.has_placeholder: #condition to add placeholder
            self.insert('1.0',self.placeholder) #add placeholder
            self.has_placeholder = True #set flag to true
            self.config(fg=self.placeholdercolor) #change text color to what you specify?

    def ret(self,index1,index2):
        if self.get('1.0','end-1c') == self.placeholder and self.has_placeholder: #gives none if there is nothing in the widget
            return 'None'
        else:
            return self.get(index1,index2) #else gives the text
root = Tk()

pl = PlaceholderText(root,placeholder='Type something here...')
pl.pack()

e = Entry(root) #dummy widget to switch focus and check
e.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

I've explained to through the comments. But keep in mind its not the best of classes yet, you have to do add a lot more methods in to make it more efficient.

Just if your wondering on how to do this without classes, then:

```
from tkinter import *

has_placeholder = False #make flag
placeholder = 'Type Something Here...' #the text to be inserted

def clear(event=None):
    global has_placeholder
    if a.get('1.0','end-1c') == placeholder and has_placeholder: #condition to clear a placeholder
        a.delete('1.0','end-1c') #delete the placeholder
        a.config(fg='grey') #change the color
        has_placeholder = False #set flag to flase

def add(event=None):
    global has_placeholder
    if a.get('1.0','end-1c') == '' and not has_placeholder: #condition to add placeholder
        a.insert('1.0',placeholder) #add placeholder
        has_placeholder = True #set flag to true
        a.config(fg='black') #change text color to normal

root = Tk()

a = Text(root)
a.pack()

add() #add the placeholder initially
a.bind('<FocusIn>',clear) #binding to focus and not button-1
a.bind('<FocusOut>',add)

e = Entry(root) #dummy widget to show focus loss
e.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Why not to use classes if the latter method is more easier? This is not reusable, say you want to add one more Text widget, that cannot have such property, while using a custom class with custom class you can have as many as text widgets with same properties you like.

Do let me know if any doubts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I don't understand classes yet, so the other solution you posted worked best for me :).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `<Key>` binding to your text widget and use your `changecolor` function to determine what state your `textbox` is in.

```
#Give a hoot. Don't pollute. :D
import tkinter as tk

txtmsg = "Type your message here"

def changecolor(event):
    text = textbox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    
    #customize accordingly
    if text:
        if text == txtmsg:
            print("text is txtmsg")
        else:
            print("text is user text")
    else:
        print("text is empty")

    #FYI:
    #whether this was a button press or key press DOES NOT have string equality
    #if you need to create button vs key conditions
    #use tk.EventType.ButtonPress and tk.EventType.KeyPress
    #or learn the .value and compare that
    print(event.type, type(event.type), event.type.value)


root = tk.Tk()

textbox = tk.Text(root, font=40, fg="grey")
textbox.insert(1.0, txtmsg)
textbox.pack()

#add events
for ev in ['<Key>', '<1>']:
    textbox.bind(ev, changecolor)

root.mainloop()
```