# Tkinter Entry box default text

Tags: python, tkinter, text, textbox

How can I program a code in python Tkinter for entry box default text?
I want to add a default text that disappears as soon I click on the entry box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding placeholders to tkinter Entry widget in a procedural way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63651586/adding-placeholders-to-tkinter-entry-widget-in-a-procedural-way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you simply would insert the default text into the `Entry` and then bind the `Entry` to getting focus and delete all that is in the entry and unbind the widget so that it doesn't delete everything in it the next time user clicks it.

```py
import tkinter as tk


def clear_default(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, 'end')
    event.widget.unbind('<FocusIn>')


root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry()
entry.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

entry.insert(0, 'Default Text')
entry.bind('<FocusIn>', clear_default)

root.mainloop()
```

Tho if it is meant to be a default not just simply a placeholder, then you could instead of deleting when the widget receives focus, select all that is in the widget, so that when user starts typing the selection is deleted. This will be also helpful if the user wants to edit their entry:

```py
entry.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda e: e.widget.select_range(0, 'end'))
```

Comment: IMO, better to bind `FocusIn`

Comment: @CoolCloud right, because of keyboard focus, will edit, it also allows for the other solution