# Auto add dashes to Line Edit PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-re, qlineedit

Is it possible to auto add dashes to PyQt5 Line Edit while the user enters the data, for example if the user wants to enter `123456789012345`, while the user enters it should be entered like `12345-67890-12345`. Also if the user enters `-` at the right position it should be accepted in. This was fairly achievable in `tkinter`, using `re`(question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62119551/auto-add-dashes-to-entryboxes-in-tkinter)), but I think it might be able to do the same with `Qt` too.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    le = QLineEdit()
    le.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ps: I have designed the GUI inside of Qt Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> inputMask : QString
>
> This property holds the validation input mask.

More https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.editingFinished)
        
        self.lineEdit.setInputMask("999-9999999;.")                                 # +++
        
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit) 
        
    def editingFinished(self):
        print(f"{self.lineEdit.text()} -> {self.lineEdit.text().replace('-', '')}")
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 22, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Did not know it was gonna be this simple. Any ways to change the insertion cursor thickness and dots there?

Comment: @CoolCloud remove `app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 22, QtGui.QFont.Bold))`

Comment: Thanks! But also I noticed that if I try to capture the empty box value, it is `'--'` could that be set to `''`? Because I am might do some evaluation if the box is empty or not later on. I think using `'--'` as definition of empty will be fine, but any other ways?

Comment: Just a small doubt regarding the link you included, does the same formats in the link for with python too?

Comment: @CoolCloud see https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/PyQt5/api/qlineedit.html and https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QLineEdit.html?highlight=inputmask#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.setInputMask