# How to get the first 9 characters starting from number 5?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have data that looks like this

```
0            504189219
1            500618053
2            0537533477
3            966581566618
4            00536079946
```

I want the output to be something like this

```
504189219
500618053
537533477
581566618
536079946
```

Comment: Looks like what you really want is the last 9 characters but I have a question. What do you want to happen if the first character of the last 9 characters is not '5' or, indeed, if there's no '5' anywhere in the string?

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.extract`:

```
df['Col'] = df['Col'].str.extract('(5\d{8})')
print(df)

# Output
         Col
0  504189219
1  500618053
2  537533477
3  581566618
4  536079946
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['504189219', '500618053', '0537533477',
                           '966581566618', '00536079946']})
print(df)

# Output
            Col
0     504189219
1     500618053
2    0537533477
3  966581566618
4   00536079946
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called `phonenumbers` to help you do that job, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058120/whats-the-best-way-to-format-a-phone-number-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Using the same setup as Corralien, this method is also possible :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['504189219', '500618053', '0537533477',
                           '966581566618', '00536079946']})

def getNumber(n):
    return n[n.find('5'):n.find('5') + 9]

df['Col'] = df['Col'].apply(getNumber)

print(df)
```

Same result can be achieved with a lambda expression as well.

Other answers originally did not take into account the constraint of the 9 numbers.

Comment: The behaviour of this is perhaps not what you'd want if/when the character '5' is absent

Comment: The author did not clarify the required behaviour, but as this is defined in a function, it's easy to catch cases where `find()` returns `-1` before returning a value.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a more robust approach:

```
import pandas as pd

def fix(col):
    return col[-9:] if len(col) > 8 and col[-9] == '5' else col


df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['0404189219', '500618053', '0537533477',
                           '966581566618', '00536079946']})

df['Col'] = df['Col'].apply(fix)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
         Col
0  0404189219
1   500618053
2   537533477
3   581566618
4   536079946
```

Note how in the absence of '5', the original value remains intact

Answer (score -1):

for r in range(len(df.Col)):
df.Col[r][df.Col[r].find("5"):]

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).