# When recalling an element from a list that contains name, ssn, salary, phone, and email... How can i format the telephone number to show (xxx)xxx-xxxx

Tags: python, list, formatting

With the code below, i can produce an employees data based on the users numerical input, but i am not sure how to format individual elements of the list such as the phone number and the salary. Thanks in advance!

```
#empty list
employee = \[\]
#employee data for loop
for i in range(5):
 print('Enter information for employee #' + str(i + 1) + '.')
 employeeName = (input('Enter employee's name: \\n'))
 employeeSSN = (input('Enter employee's SSN: \\n'))
 employeePhone = int(input('Enter employee's 10-Digit Phone #: \\n'))
 employeeEmail = (input('Enter employee's Email: \\n'))
 employeeSalary = (input('Enter employee's Salary: \\n'))
 employee.append(\[employeeName, employeeSSN,employeePhone,employeeEmail,employeeSalary\])
#index
index = int(input('Enter a value 1-5 to print corresponding employee information, or 0 to exit.'))

if index == 1:
print(employee\[0\])



elif index == 2:
 print(employee\[1\])
elif index == 3:
 print(employee\[2\])
elif index == 4:
 print(employee\[3\])
elif (index== 5):
 print(employee\[4\])
else:
 print('Goodbye!')
```

i tried adding the following and creating a new variable to format the phone number but could not make it work.I just cant figure out how to format parts of an element of a list.

```
#empty list
employee = \[\]
#employee data for loop
for i in range(5):
 print('Enter information for employee #' + str(i + 1) + '.')
 employeeName = (input('Enter employee's name: \\n'))
 employeeSSN = (input('Enter employee's SSN: \\n'))
 employeePhone = int(input('Enter employee's 10-Digit Phone #: \\n'))
 last4 = employeePhone % 10000
 mid3 = employeePhone % 1000
 areaCode = employeePhone
 Phone = ('(',areaCode,')',mid3,'-',last4)
 employeeEmail = (input('Enter employee's Email: \\n'))
 employeeSalary = (input('Enter employee's Salary: \\n'))
 employee.append(\[employeeName, employeeSSN,Phone,employeeEmail,employeeSalary\])
#index
index = int(input('Enter a value 1-5 to print corresponding employee information, or 0 to exit.'))

if index == 1:
 print(employee\[0\])
elif index == 2:
 print(employee\[1\])
elif index == 3:
 print(employee\[2\])
elif index == 4:
 print(employee\[3\])
elif (index== 5):
 print(employee\[4\])
else:
 print('Goodbye!')\`
```

Comment: You should be able to use the phonenumbers package to format the number.  See the previous question where this was answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058120/whats-the-best-way-to-format-a-phone-number-in-python.

Comment: Why do you have backslashes before all your brackets?

Answer (score 1):

A solution to your problem could be:

```
employee = []
#employee data for loop
for i in range(1):
    print('Enter information for employee #' + str(i + 1) + '.')
employeeName = input("Enter employee's name:\n")
employeeSSN = input("Enter employee's SSN:\n")
employeePhone = int(input("Enter employee's 10-Digit Phone\n"))
Phone = "({}){}-{}".format(str(employeePhone)[:3], str(employeePhone)[3:6], str(employeePhone)[6:])
employeeEmail = (input("Enter employee's Email: \n"))
employeeSalary = (input("Enter employee's Salary: \n"))
employee.append([employeeName, employeeSSN,Phone,employeeEmail,employeeSalary])
#index
index = int(input('Enter a value 1-5 to print corresponding employee information, or 0 to exit: '))

if index == 1:
 print(employee[0])
elif index == 2:
 print(employee[1])
elif index == 3:
 print(employee[2])
elif index == 4:
 print(employee[3])
elif (index== 5):
 print(employee[4])
else:
 print('Goodbye!')
```

Where *employeePhone* is formatted through the *format()* method from the 10 digits number entered to the (xxx)xxx-xxxx format.

```
Phone = "({}){}-{}".format(str(employeePhone)[:3], str(employeePhone)[3:6], str(employeePhone)[6:])
```