# ObjectListView Sorting and Formatting Integers with Commas?

Tags: python, sorting, csv, integer, objectlistview

I'm running Python 2.7 and I've got an `ObjectListView` displaying loads of demographic info. I can get it to sort correctly, but the output is displayed in `100000.0` format.  When I convert the integer to a string using the locale module, it sorts the descending strings like `9,181, 9,069, 818, 813, 8,730,` etc. Any ideas how to sort like integers, but display the output as comma formatted in the `ObjectListView`?

Comment: Sort the data before the formatting. If `ObjectListView` is like most datagrid components (i.e. kind of terrible at non-RAD use cases), you'll have to implement custom sorting for that column.

Comment: From skimming the `ObjectListView` documentation, it seems like it should sort based on the underlying model value. Can you show some example of how you're wiring this up and where you're converting the number to a string? (Make it a simple example if possible, like with a dummy class that only has one integer column.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for putting me on the right track! In the end I just ended up adding two lines to the ObjectListView.py source. Around line 3601, I changed the _StringToValue Function to include:

```
    if converter == "%cd": ##New Line
        return locale.format("%d", value, grouping=True) ##New Line
    else:
     fmt = converter or "%s"
     try:
        return fmt % value
     except UnicodeError:
        return unicode(fmt) % value
```

also needed to set locale after the local import, as show above:

```
  locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
```

Thank you, I've been pounding my head on this one for a while now. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can order `yourColumn` by their integer values rather than their display string using:

```
yourColumn = ColumnDefn("Title", "center", 100, "title", stringConverter=int_to_string_with_commas)
```

-- *[see smarter string conversions](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/gettingStarted.html#smarter-string-conversions)*.

.

Where `int_to_string_with_commas` is a function converting integers to strings (with commas):

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US') # your locale here

def int_to_string_with_commas(value):
    return locale.format("%d", value, grouping=True)
```

*For other ways to do write `int_to_string_with_commas` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-python-2-x).*

.

Comment: Your formatting function is kind of worse than the OP's approach. Using `locale` to format this the way that's set up on the user's system is the way to go - hardcoding the format would go beside the point of this. (That said, the way the column is defined might be helpful. Can't really say without the OP providing code.)

Comment: @millimoose However you code, [int_to_string_with_commas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-python-2-x) the `yourColumn` line will be the same. The point is, it will order like value, rather than `int_to_string_with_commas(value)`.

Comment: I understand what you're getting at, it's just that it's mildly confusing to suggest an inferior implementation of the function than the one the OP already says he has done correctly, even if it's tangential to the actual question. (For that matter, so is spending half your answer on a tangential concern.) I'd just use an obviously dummy or vague implementation, since it's not important how the string is being formatted.

Comment: @millimoose Rearranged to add the more important section first (and used locale.)