# How can I save numbers with comma delimiter stored as string as an integer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, delimiter

Result must include the delimiter.

Ex: `a='1,000'` of type string and the output must be: `a=1,000` as an integer.

Comment: If you want to use a delimiter like this in Py3.6, use the underscore, e.g. `int('1_000')`, see PEP 515

Comment: For convenience the link: [PEP-515](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Python to convert a string to a number if it has commas in it as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-th)

Answer (score 2):

An integer won't include a comma. It's only for making the number readable that you add commas to it.

If you meant you want to parse the string into an integer, you should do the following:

```
num = int(a.replace(',', ''))
```

Afterwards if you want to present this integer with a comma again, you should just:

```
print "{:,}".format(num)
```

For back and fourth conversion in execution:
[Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686629/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-a-comma-separated-string) and [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x) can help

Comment: This is useful if you have to stay on `,` as delimiter. Otherwise [Chris_Rands comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551510/how-can-i-save-numbers-with-comma-delimiter-stored-as-string-as-an-integer-in-py#comment92042027_52551510) is the way of doing it.