# Pandas Dataframe Number Values Comma Formatted

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I have a Pandas dataframe like below.

```
    X        Y
0  12345    67890
1  54321    N/A
2  67890    123456
```

I need to make these numbers comma formatted. For example, 12345 => 12,345.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686629/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-a-comma-separated-string)

Comment: I need all the numbers in the whole dataframe to be formatted like that, 
not one value. Also, note that, there is a string value there. It should not be changed.

Comment: Use the apply function on the column. Filter out the ints using lambda

Answer (score 1):

```
nan = 'N/A'

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(10000,20000, 6), 'B':np.random.randint(1000,2000, 6)})
df.loc[3,'B'] = nan

df = df.replace(nan, 0)
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: '{:,}'.format(x))
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: '{:,}'.format(x))
```

Comment: It's giving error - Cannot specify ',' with 's'. Also, I am not talking about NaN. It's a string "N/A".

Comment: There could be a zero (0) in the column.

Comment: Do you mean a string like this '(0)' ?

Comment: No, integer 0. That would give me trouble once I would need to replace back 0 to 'N/A'

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Y'] = df['Y'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df['Y'] = df['Y'].apply(lambda x: '{:,.0f}'.format(x))
df['Y'] = df['Y'].replace({'nan' : 'N/A'}, regex=True)
```

I guess there must be better ways.
Thanks Marco Cerliani.