# Generate tailor made thousand delimiter

Tags: python, number-formatting

I want to tailor-make a thousand delimiter in Python. I am generating HTML and want to use `&thinsp;` as thousand separator. (It would look like: 1 000 000)

So far I have found the following way to add a `,` as a separator:

```
>>> '{0:,}'.format(1000000)
'1,000,000'
```

But I don't see to be able to use a similar construction to get another delimiter. `'{0:|}'.format(1000000)` for example does not work. Is there an easy way to use anything (*i.e.*, `&thinsp;`) as a thousand separator?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11562205/515948) you can find a regexp-based approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can always do this:

```
'{0:,}'.format(1000000).replace(',', '|')
```

Result: `'1|000|000'`

---

Here's a simple algorithm for the same. The previous version of it (`ThSep` two revisions back) didn't handle long separators like `&thinsp;`:

```
def ThSep(num, sep = ','):
    num = int(num)

    if not num:
        return '0'

    ret = ''
    dig = 0
    neg = False

    if num < 0:
        num = -num
        neg = True

    while num != 0:
        dig += 1
        ret += str(num % 10)
        if (dig == 3) and (num / 10):
            for ch in reversed(sep):
                ret += ch
            dig = 0

        num /= 10

    if neg:
        ret += '-'

    return ''.join(reversed(ret))
```

Call it with `ThSep(1000000, '&thinsp;')` or `ThSep(1000000, '|')` to get the result you want.

It's about 4 times slower than the first method, though, so you can try rewriting this as a C extension for production code. This is only if speed matters much. I converted 2 000 000 negative and positive numbers in half a minute for the test.

Comment: @BhargavRao, nothing. In the previous revision, __`ThSep`__ couldn't handle them, not the version with `replace`

Comment: Thanks for that. However, PEP 378 already mentions that replace is the correct way. So I guess it is a bit of reinventing the wheel! Anyway, tis not wrong at all. Good answer. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in way to do this, But you can use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), if the number is the only present value

```
>>> '{0:,}'.format(1000000).replace(',','|')
'1|000|000'
```

This is mentioned in [PEP 378](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/#id21)

> The proposal works well with floats, ints, and decimals. It also allows easy substitution for other separators. For example:
>
> ```
> format(n, "6,d").replace(",", "_")
> ```