# Python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"(\d{3})+$")
print pattern.match("123567").groups()
```

output result:

```
('567',)
```

I need the result is `('123','567')`.
The `(\d{3})` only can output last group, but I want output every group.

Comment: remove the `$` and also `+` from regex..

Comment: `re.findall("\d{3}", "123567")`

Comment: when I remove `$` , the result is same.

Comment: What output do you expect if the string length is not a multiple of 3?

Comment: You've a greedy match? Try `re.compile(r"(\d{3}?)+$")`?

Comment: I want ('123','567')

Comment: So if the string is `"1235678"` you still want ('123', '567') leaving the last letter.

Comment: In that case, you want `findall`

Comment: @user5673769 from your comments on the other answer it seems you want this behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing it in a bit of pythonic way

**Solution 1**

*Python Code*

```
p = re.compile(r'(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)')
test_str = "2890191245"
tmp = [x.start() for x in re.finditer(p, test_str)]
res = [test_str[0: tmp[0]]] + [(test_str[tmp[i]: tmp[i] + 3]) for i in range(len(tmp))]
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/pdLfqO)**

**Solution 2** (one liner)

```
print(re.sub("(?<=\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)", ",", test_str).split(","))
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/Zyy3Ol)**

Comment: The answer is right, but I don't understand `p = re.compile(r'(\d{3})')`. Could you explain it ?

Comment: Yes! However the OP has still not answered what would be the expected output in case of `"1235678"`.

Comment: @user5673769 its same as you mentioned in your regex except this is finding all the _non-overlapping_ combination of three digits present in the string

Comment: @AKS I think what you are implying is to also find overlapping patterns..is it that?

Comment: Not exactly what I am thinking that does the OP want the result to be `[123, 567, 8]` or just `[123, 567]`.

Comment: @AKS `8` is not a 3 digit string so shouldn't be there.

Comment: @AKS maybe..but OP is asking for exact three digits

Comment: @ozgur yes I know that. I am just trying to get a sense of the expected output when this condition occurs. But it seems OP does want groups of 3 digits from start leaving the remainders.

Comment: @rock321987 your answer can solve `123456`,but cannot solve `2389019`. When the `s=2389019`, the answer is `None`. I want the answer is [2,389,019].

Comment: @ozgur do you see in the comment above 2 is also not a 3 digit string and the output OP is expecting is totally different.

Comment: @rock321987 That's great. However I have this feeling that OP is after something like this: https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-378-format-specifier-for-thousands-separator

Comment: @AKS actually my regex was inspired from Mastering Regular Expression which was doing exact same thing as mentioned in the link but only using regex replace

Comment: @rock321987 The question is similar with AKS, but I hope I can find a easy solution way and I think regular expression is powerful. And I think using   regular expression dealing with question about string is more convenience than using other tools.Thank you spending time solve this question.