# Adding comma separators to a string in a Dataframe Column with pandas

Tags: regex, pandas

[image: Top15.head()]

I am trying to add comma separators to indicate thousands to my string to a column in a dataframe. Can someone help with format? I do not understand how to do this to an entire column in a dataframe

```
Top15['PopEst'] = re.sub("(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))", r"\1,", "%d" % Top15['PopEst'])
```

Comment: FYI, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11562205/3832970

Comment: I got the code from there originally. I do not understand how to do this for the entire row in the dataframe.

Comment: Use df['column_name'].apply() method.

Comment: Can you include the df.head() part in your question?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
Top15["PopEst"] = Top15["PopEst"].map(lambda x: "{:,}".format(x))
```

The `"{:,}".format()` would work as a thousand separator for a single `string`/`float`/`int`, so you can use `map()` to apply it to each of the elements in column.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
v= format(12345678, ',d')
print(v)
//12,345,678
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Top15['PopEst']=(Top15['Energy Supply']/Top15['Energy Supply per Capita'])
df = Top15[['PopEst']]
df = df.reset_index()

i=0
while(len(df)>i):
    v =str(df.iloc[i]['PopEst']).split('.')

    strr = str(format(int(v[0]), ',d'))+"."+v[1]

    df.iloc[i] = df.iloc[i].replace(df.iloc[i]['PopEst'],strr)

    i = i+1

df.set_index(['Country Name'], inplace=True)
```