# Convert an amount to Indian Notation in Python

Tags: python, formatting, currency

**Problem:** I need to convert an amount to Indian currency format

**My code:** I have the following `Python` implementation:

```
import decimal
def currencyInIndiaFormat(n):
  d = decimal.Decimal(str(n))
  if d.as_tuple().exponent < -2:
    s = str(n)
  else:
    s = '{0:.2f}'.format(n)
  l = len(s)
  i = l-1;
  res = ''
  flag = 0
  k = 0
  while i>=0:
    if flag==0:
      res = res + s[i]
      if s[i]=='.':
        flag = 1
    elif flag==1:
      k = k + 1
      res = res + s[i]
      if k==3 and i-1>=0:
        res = res + ','
        flag = 2
        k = 0
    else:
      k = k + 1
      res = res + s[i]
      if k==2 and i-1>=0:
        res = res + ','
        flag = 2
        k = 0
    i = i - 1

  return res[::-1]

def main():
  n = 100.52
  print "INR " + currencyInIndiaFormat(n)  # INR 100.52
  n = 1000.108
  print "INR " + currencyInIndiaFormat(n)  # INR 1,000.108
  n = 1200000
  print "INR " + currencyInIndiaFormat(n)  # INR 12,00,000.00

main()
```

**My Question:** Is there a way to make my *currencyInIndiaFormat* function **shorter, more concise and clean** ? / Is there a better way to write my *currencyInIndiaFormat* function ?

**Note:** My question is mainly based on `Python` implementation of the above stated problem. *It is not a duplicate of previously asked questions regarding conversion of currency to Indian format.*

**Indian Currency Format:**

For example, numbers here are represented as:

```
1
10
100
1,000
10,000
1,00,000
10,00,000
1,00,00,000
10,00,00,000
```

Refer [Indian Numbering System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)

Comment: Can you enlighten us about the Indian currency format?

Comment: There's a lot of single variable names in there. Making those more descriptive would be the easiest win. Also, this should be on Code Review.

Comment: @DYZ: Added Indian currency format!!!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Too much work.

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN')
'en_IN'
>>> print(locale.currency(100.52, grouping=True))
₹ 100.52
>>> print(locale.currency(1000.108, grouping=True))
₹ 1,000.11
>>> print(locale.currency(1200000, grouping=True))
₹ 12,00,000.00
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me,I get following message Error: unsupported locale setting

Comment: Then install the locale, or use a similar one.

Comment: Can't seem to install locales on OSX, apparently.

Comment: This work., However you need to configure locale in your local machine a swell. Just type locale in your terminal shell in linux.. If the used locale is not present in local machine. It will throw the error.

Comment: How do we install en_IN locale on macOS Mojave ?

Comment: Thou it is working but only issue I can see is `currency symbol` is showing `?`.

Answer (score 18):

Simple version:

```
def formatINR(number):
    s, *d = str(number).partition(".")
    r = ",".join([s[x-2:x] for x in range(-3, -len(s), -2)][::-1] + [s[-3:]])
    return "".join([r] + d)
```

Sample:

```
print(formatINR(123456))
```

Output:

```
1,23,456
```

If you want to handle negative numbers and strings,

```
def formatINR(number):
    number = float(number)
    number = round(number,2)
    is_negative = number < 0
    number = abs(number)
    s, *d = str(number).partition(".")
    r = ",".join([s[x-2:x] for x in range(-3, -len(s), -2)][::-1] + [s[-3:]])
    value = "".join([r] + d)
    if is_negative:
       value = '-' + value
    return '₹'+ value
```

Sample:

```
print(formatINR('-004.256'))
```

Output:

```
₹-4.26
```

Comment: Why is this not upvoted more ?
It's the simplest solution!

Comment: The easiest one here. Thanks!

Comment: @hargun3045 not production level, has few case where it fails, it only assume that passing function parameter is decimal or integer only, in case it is string having `0000` in starting of it it wont remove them and will show unwanted result, so whoever is using this function just check the number you are passing

Answer (score 15):

You can follow these steps.
Install Babel python package from pip

```
pip install Babel
```

In your python script

```
from babel.numbers import format_currency
format_currency(5433422.8012, 'INR', locale='en_IN')
```

Output:

```
₹ 54,33,422.80
```

Comment: This one provide correct output but quite slower than `locale`.

Answer (score 3):

> **Note - THIS IS AN ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION FOR ACTUAL QUESTION**

If anyone trying to convert in simple Indian terms like `K`, `L`, or `Cr` with 2 floating-point values, the following solution would work.

```
def format_cash(amount):
    def truncate_float(number, places):
        return int(number * (10 ** places)) / 10 ** places

    if amount < 1e3:
        return amount

    if 1e3 <= amount < 1e5:
        return str(truncate_float((amount / 1e5) * 100, 2)) + " K"

    if 1e5 <= amount < 1e7:
        return str(truncate_float((amount / 1e7) * 100, 2)) + " L"

    if amount > 1e7:
        return str(truncate_float(amount / 1e7, 2)) + " Cr"
```

**Examples**

```
format_cash(7843) --> '7.84 K'
format_cash(78436) --> '78.43 K'
format_cash(784367) --> '7.84 L'
format_cash(7843678) --> '78.43 L'
format_cash(78436789) --> '7.84 Cr'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the other way around:

```
import re
def in_for(value):
    value,b=str(value),''
    value=''.join(map(lambda va:va if re.match(r'[0-9,.]',va) else '',value))
    val=value
    if val.count(',')==0:
        v,c,a,cc,ii=val,0,[3,2,2],0,0
        val=val[:val.rfind('.')] if val.rfind('.')>=0  else val
        for i in val[::-1]:
            if c==ii and c!=0:
                ii+=a[cc%3]
                b=','+i+b
                cc+=1  
            else:
                b=i+b
            c+=1
        b=b[1:] if b[0]==',' else b
        val=b+v[value.rfind('.'):]  if value.rfind('.')>=0  else b
    else:
        val=str(val).strip('()').replace(' ','')
    v=val.rfind('.')
    if v>0:
        val=val[:v+3]
    return val.rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if '.' in val else val

print(in_for('1000000000000.5445'))
```

**Output will be:**

```
10,000,00,00,000.54
```

(As mentioned in wikipedia indian number system Ex:67,89,000,00,00,000)

Answer (score 1):

```
def format_indian(t):
dic = {
    4:'Thousand',
    5:'Lakh',
    6:'Lakh',
    7:'Crore',
    8:'Crore',
    9:'Arab'
}
y = 10
len_of_number = len(str(t))
save = t
z=y
while(t!=0):
   t=int(t/y)
   z*=10

zeros = len(str(z)) - 3
if zeros>3:
    if zeros%2!=0:
        string = str(save)+": "+str(save/(z/100))[0:4]+" "+dic[zeros]
    else:   
        string = str(save)+": "+str(save/(z/1000))[0:4]+" "+dic[zeros]
    return string
return str(save)+": "+str(save)
```

This code will Convert Yout Numbers to Lakhs, Crores and arabs in most simplest way. Hope it helps.

```
for i in [1.234567899 * 10**x for x in range(9)]:
print(format_indian(int(i)))
```

Output:

```
1: 1
12: 12
123: 123
1234: 1234
12345: 12.3 Thousand
123456: 1.23 Lakh
1234567: 12.3 Lakh
12345678: 1.23 Crore
123456789: 12.3 Crore
```

Answer (score 1):

As pgksunilkumar's answer, a little improvement is done in case the number is in between 0 to -1000

```
def formatINR(number):
    neg = False
    if number < 0:
        neg = True
    number = abs(number)
    s, *d = str(number).partition(".")
    r = ",".join([s[x-2:x] for x in range(-3, -len(s), -2)][::-1] + [s[-3:]])
    r = "-"+r if neg else r
    return "".join([r] + d)
```

now if the number is between 0 to -1000, the format will not disturb the user.

i.e

```
a = -600
b = -10000000
c = 700
d = 8000000
e = -30850

print(formatINR(a))
print(formatINR(b))
print(formatINR(c))
print(formatINR(d))
print(formatINR(e))
```

output will be:

```
-600
-1,00,00,000
700
80,00,000
-30,850
```

Comment: Based on current definition also it won't disturb as per your use case also

Comment: But it shows in negative value start at "," . For example I pass the value "-33085.00"  it return as -,33,085.0.

Answer (score 0):

> Another way:

```
def formatted_int(value):
    # if the value is 100, 10, 1

    if len(str(value)) <= 3:
        return value

    # if the value is 10,000, 1,000
    elif  3 < len(str(value)) <= 5:
        return f'{str(value)[:-3]},{str(value)[-3:]} ₹'

    # if the value is greater the 10,000    
    else:
        cut = str(value)[:-3]  
        o = []
        while cut:
            o.append(cut[-2:]) # appending from 1000th value(right to left)
            cut = cut[:-2]
        
        o = o[::-1] # reversing list
        res = ",".join(o) 
        
        return f'{res},{str(value)[-3:]} ₹'


value1 = 1_00_00_00_000
value2 = 10_00_00_00_000          
value3 = 100

print(formatted_int(value1))
print(formatted_int(value2))
print(formatted_int(value3))
```

> Ouput:

```
    1,00,00,00,000 ₹

    10,00,00,00,000 ₹

    100 ₹
```

Comment: `print(formatted_int(100-1000))` gives the output like `-,900`

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't make the other two solutions work for me, so I made something a little more low-tech:

```
def format_as_indian(input):
    input_list = list(str(input))
    if len(input_list) <= 1:
        formatted_input = input
    else:
        first_number = input_list.pop(0)
        last_number = input_list.pop()
        formatted_input = first_number + (
            (''.join(l + ',' * (n % 2 == 1) for n, l in enumerate(reversed(input_list)))[::-1] + last_number)
        )

        if len(input_list) % 2 == 0:
            formatted_input.lstrip(',')

    return formatted_input
```

This doesn't work with decimals. If you need that, I would suggest saving the decimal portion into another variable and adding it back in at the end.

Answer (score -1):

```
num=123456789
snum=str(num)
slen=len(snum)
result=''

if (slen-3)%2 !=0 :
    snum='x'+snum

for i in range(0,slen-3,2):
    result=result+snum[i:i+2]+','
    
result+=snum[slen-3:]
print(result.replace('x',''))
```

Comment: # Taking Input 
# Excluding last 3 digits.. %2 to verify remaing length of str is even or add..If even..Lite..Else..Add an extra character x in the begining
# Iterate string(number) from 0 to len-3..By taking step count 2..Adding two two values to result set
#finally combing both last 3 digits with result set which was just generated

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: To expand on @Tyler2P's point, this is _especially_ important here, where there are six other answers, including an accepted answer with quite a few upvotes from five years ago. What sets your answer apart? Why were the existing answers insufficient? Are you taking advantage of new syntax that wasn't available when the original answers were written? Help readers understand why they should consider your approach.

Answer (score -1):

Those who needed it for Pandas float_format in Jupyter Notebook,

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN')

pd.options.display.float_format = lambda x : locale.currency(x, grouping=True)
```