# How to print number with commas as lakhs separators?

Tags: python-3.x

How to print number with commas as lakhs separators?

```
For Ex: 
val = 1023456
output = 10,23,456

val = 12345676
output = 123,45,676
```

Comment: This post can answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951552/convert-an-amount-to-indian-notation-in-python

Answer (score 0):

thanx for your prompt reply but I'm expecting the output format(1023456)) is 10,23,456 as lakhs separators and then in thousand separators

Comment: reply with comment, not answer? And welcome to SO(Stack Overflow)!