# How to set a custom thousands separator?

Tags: python, formatting, integer, locale

I know that theoretically digits in large integers can be grouped by thousands for better readability:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> locale.format('%d', 1234567890, grouping=True)
'1,234,567,890'
>>> "{:n}".format(1234567890)
'1,234,567,890'
```

However, surprisingly, this won’t work for every locale:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pl_PL.UTF-8')
'pl_PL.UTF-8'
>>> locale.format('%d', 1234567890, grouping=True)
'1234567890'
>>> "{:n}".format(1234567890)
'1234567890'
```

Why are numbers not formatted? I find this strange. I would expect something like `1 234 567 890` being printed.

Per [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), we can explicitly enforce two possible separators: a comma `,` and an underscore `_`. Sadly, a comma is inappropriate for Polish since it is used as a decimal point separator there, and a number like `1_234_567_890` would look oddly for most people.

Can we somehow enforce a non-breaking space  being used as a thousands separator?

Comment: Workaround: `"1_234_567_890".replace("_", '.')` gives you what you want

Comment: `locale.currency(var, symbol=False, grouping=True)`, since `pl_PL` does include `.` separators for monetary values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print number with commas as thousands separators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators)

Comment: @Prune: The questioner wants periods, not commas.

Comment: @Prune And in addition I am very well aware how to set up commas, I mentioned that in my post.

Comment: Yes, but work-around solutions in that post show how to choose your own separator.  **locale**'s grouping feature doesn't let you override the location's settings.  All you can do with that is to set a location that has the features you want.  I didn't find one.

Comment: My bad: I checked out what linguists say and apparently, using a dot is an error. Not using a separator is wrong as well. Instead, a non-breaking space should be used.

Answer (score 1):

The `pl_PL` locale thousands separator seems to be [empty](http://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/pl_PL/). I don't know if this accurately represents common usage in Poland, but Python is correctly formatting your number according to the rules of the `pl_PL` locale. This may be a bug in the locale files.

As far as I am aware, there is no option to manually specify the thousands separator and decimal mark characters.