# Pandas to_csv how to format both int and float variables with comma as thousands separator

Tags: python, pandas, csv, number-formatting

All the data I crunch needs to be reported with comma as thousands separator. I'm only interested in values with comma as thousands separator after the data is written to a .csv file. Internally within my pandas dataframe, I want to keep them as int or float.

#### floats

I can output the floats to zero decimal with:

```
 df.to_csv('c:\Awesome\Groovy.csv', float_format = '%.0f')
```

but whenever I try to put a comma in the float it doesn't work.

```
 df.to_csv('c:\Awesome\Groovy.csv', float_format = ':,.0f') ## WRONG
 df.to_csv('c:\Awesome\Groovy.csv', float_format = {:,.0f}'.format) ## WRONG
```

#### ints

And my plan for the ints, is first to convert them to float in the dataframe and then format them with the .to_csv function. Any thoughts?

Comment: As you've seen new-style format strings are not supported by pandas at the moment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2502

Comment: You're using the term 'comma separated values' wrong, you don't mean CSV, you mean 'comma as thousands separator'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be too kludgy for you. At any rate here goes. Using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205875/42346 we can have our commas:

```
def thous(x, sep=',', dot='.'):
    num, _, frac = str(x).partition(dot)
    num = re.sub(r'(\d{3})(?=\d)', r'\1'+sep, num[::-1])[::-1]
    if frac:
        num += dot + frac
    return num

df['my_column'] = df['my_column'].apply(lambda x: thous(x))
```

Using some sample data I had lying around from another SO question:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-11','2017-03-12'],
                       'activate_time':['2017-03-10 12:13:30','2017-03-11 13:57:49','2017-03-12 14:28:05'],
                       'mycol':[1234.56789,9876.54321,1111111.11111]})
>>> df['mycol'] = df['mycol'].apply(lambda x: thous(x))
>>> df
          activate_time        date            mycol
0   2017-03-10 12:13:30  2017-03-10      1,234.56789
1   2017-03-11 13:57:49  2017-03-11      9,876.54321
2   2017-03-12 14:28:05  2017-03-12  1,111,111.11111
```

Comment: It seems to work for what I need, but I wanted it rounded so I modified : `def thous(x, sep=',', dot='.'):
    y = round(x)
    num, _, frac = str(y).partition(dot)
    num = re.sub(r'(\d{3})(?=\d)', r'\1'+sep, num[::-1])[::-1]
#     if frac:
#         num += dot + frac
    return num`

Comment: then just looped through my dataframe:  `for x in list(df):
    df[x] = df[x].apply(lambda x: thous(x))`  So Thanks!

Comment: Cheers, mate. Good on you for coming up with that modification. By the way, I'm jealous that you only work with CSVs!

Comment: The csv's are the end product, plenty of wacky stuff to start with. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up with based on bernie's answer above. I wanted to post it here for other folks.

```
import re
def thous(x, sep=',', dot='.'):
   y = round(x)
   num, _, frac = str(y).partition(dot)
   num = re.sub(r'(\d{3})(?=\d)', r'\1'+sep, num[::-1])[::-1]
   #  comment out for no 0    if frac:
   #  comment out for no 0   num += dot + frac
   return num

num = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]) #selects only numeric dtypes
for x in num:
     df[x] = df[x].apply(lambda x: thous(x))
```

run it just before you use the to_csv command and you're golden. Cheers!