# use string format() to format a number

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to format a series of float to show comma delimitation every 3 digits:

```
1234567.89123
```

should become

```
1,234,567.89123
```

without using:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')
```

I could convert the float to string and insert commas every three digits starting from left of the decimal dot... 
Is there a nicer way?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10742904/6153990).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print number with commas as thousands separators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Refer to this for more information on how to format*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

```
s = pd.Series([12345678.9876] * 3)

s.apply('{:,}'.format)

0    12,345,678.9876
1    12,345,678.9876
2    12,345,678.9876
dtype: object
```

---

`pandas` also allows you to set options temporarily with `pd.option_context`

```
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:,}'.format):
    print(s)

0   12,345,678.9876
1   12,345,678.9876
2   12,345,678.9876
dtype: float64
```