# How to format a long variable to use commas in python

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, number-formatting

Hi i would like to format the variable volume before it is printed as so below, i cant seem to find a tut that helps correctly.

```
def volume_sphere(radius): 
    """radius = 12,742 / 2 (earth diameter)"""
    pi = 3.141592653589
    volume = ( 4 / 3 ) * pi * radius ** 3 
    format('{:20,.2f}'.format(volume))
#    volume format 0,000,000,000,000,000,000


    print ("Calculate volume of a sphere (The Earth) \nvolume = ( 4 / 3 ) * pi * radius ** 3")
    print ("Radius = ", radius, "Kms")
    print ("The volume of the earth = ", volume, "Kms3\n\n")


volume_sphere(6371)
```

Comment: See > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators

Comment: What is the expected output and your output for your input (6371)?

Comment: I fixed it with     print ("The volume of the earth = ", '{:20,.2f}'.format(volume), "Kms3\n\n")

Comment: now i would like to format the variable before the print is called so i dont have to do the formatting in print and the variable is always correct no matter where i call it from

Comment: why did i receive a minus three for this???

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the formatting.

```
print ("The volume of the earth = ", '{:20,.2f}'.format(volume), "Kms3\n\n")
```

Enjoy!!!