# Python: Thousands Separator - old Formatting Syntax

Tags: python, string

With the new formatting syntax, Python can easily be made to print a thousands separator:

```
print ("{0:,.2f} Euro".format(myVariable))
```

So the comma takes care for this.

How can this be done with the old syntax - without using locale?

```
print ("%.2f Euro" % myVariable)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`printf`-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=printf#printf-style-string-formatting) does not support thousand separator.

You need to build a string with thousand separator:

```
>>> amount = 12345
>>> '%s Euro' % format(amount, ',.2f')
'12,345.00 Euro'
```

Built-in function [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) uses the same [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) that [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) uses.

If you can't use `format`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators) for alternatives.