# Reading cell value in python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, formatting, openpyxl

I have an excel coming from external source. I have a value in a cell which is 63.999 as shown below :

[image]

but in the top editing bar it is shown as 63999 as shown below :

[image]

I am using openpyxl to parse this Excel and it gives me 63999 as cell value.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(SigLexiconFilePath)
sheet = wb.active
print (sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value)
```

How to get 63.999 using openpyxl?

Comment: The value is not a decimal value. It's an integer with value: `63999`. The point `.` is a thousands separator, not a decimal separator. So, either the value that you are parsing is not a decimal value or your parsing it the wrong way. Could you show your code?

Comment: but i want to read it as it is inside the cell

Comment: Yes I know, but since the value that is in the excel sheet is `63999` and the value you are reading is `63999`, I don't know what you want. Do you want to convert it to the decimal value `63.999` or to a string with a thousands separator?

Comment: I put the code in question. I want to read 63.999 which is shown in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

To print the value with a thousands separator you can use the following code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10742904/8873143):

```
"{:,}".format(value)
```

For your code that would be:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(SigLexiconFilePath)
sheet = wb.active
print ("{:,}".format(sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value))
```

If you want to use a `.` instead of a `,`, you can use the following code instead:

```
"{:,}".format(value).replace(',', ' ')
```

Comment: why it is shown as 63.999 inside the cell and 63999 inside the editing bar?

Comment: Like I said in comment on your question, `63999` is an integer and the `63.999` is just the same number with a thousands separator. You can check out [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-or-hide-the-thousands-separator-b9f8aee0-ef50-42e5-8fd7-6e3ab1493876) tutorial by Microsoft on how to disable the thousands separator if you would like to, so you can see that it is not a decimal number.

Comment: but the real value is 63.999 . Here . represents decimel number. its not a thousand operator.

Comment: How do you know that it is a decimal number? Because if that is the case, the editing bar would not show you the number as an integer.

Comment: Ok. I will check once again with the excel provider.