# Format a large integer with commas without using .format()

Tags: python

I'm trying to format any number by inserting ',' every 3 numbers from the end by not using `format()`

> 123456789 becomes 123,456,789
>
> 1000000 becomes 1,000,000

What I have so far only seems to go from the start, I've tried different ideas to get it to reverse but they seem to not work as I hoped.

```
def format_number(number):
    s = [x for x in str(number)]

    for a in s[::3]:
        if s.index(a) is not 0:
             s.insert(s.index(a), ',')
    return ''.join(s)

print(format_number(1123456789))

>> 112,345,678,9
```

But obviously what I want is 1,123,456,789

I tried reversing the range `[:-1:3]` but I get `112,345,6789`

**Clarification:** I don't want to use format to structure the number, I'd prefer to understand how to do it myself just for self-study's sake.

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to use built-in functions? I'm sure a quick function could easily solve this for you.

Comment: You can use `[::-3]` instead. That will reverse the range.

Comment: Aren't you using `print`, `index`, `insert` and `join`?  Aren't they built-in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print number with commas as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: it's related, but not a dupe given the "without using builtin functions" requirement (even though that's not well-defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for you, without using built-in functions:

```
def format_number(number):
    s = list(str(number))[::-1]
    o = ''
    for a in range(len(s)):
        if a and a % 3 == 0:
            o += ','
        o += s[a]
    return o[::-1]


print(format_number(1123456789))
```

And here is the same solution using built-in functions:

```
def format_number(number):
    return '{:,}'.format(number)


print(format_number(1123456789))
```

I hope this helps. :D

Comment: Technically `range`, `len`, `list` and `str` are all built-in functions... but then the OP's attempt also uses some of these.

Comment: My question wasn't specific but you got what I was trying to say, I didn't want to use `.format()` but I wanted to try and do it manually, but couldn't. Thanks for being understanding!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it without built-in functions at all...

```
def format_number(number):
    i = 0
    r = ""
    while True:
        r = "0123456789"[number % 10] + r
        number //= 10
        if number == 0:
            return r
        i += 1
        if i % 3 == 0:
            r = "," + r
```

Here's a version that's *almost* free of built-in functions or methods (it does still have to use `str`)

```
def format_number(number):
    i = 0
    r = ""
    for character in str(number)[::-1]:
        if i > 0 and i % 3 == 0:
            r = "," + r
        r = character + r
        i += 1

    return r
```

Another way to do it without `format` but with other built-ins is to reverse the number, split it into chunks of 3, join them with a comma, and reverse it again.

```
def format_number(number):
    backward = str(number)[::-1]
    r = ",".join(backward[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(backward), 3))
    return r[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach has following drawbacks

- checking for equality/inequality in most cases (especially for `int`) should be made using `==`/`!=` operators, not `is`/`is not` ones,
- using `list.index` returns first occurence from the left end (so `s.index('1')` will be always `0` in your example), we can iterate over range if indices instead (using [`range` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)).

we can have something like

```
def format_number(number):
    s = [x for x in str(number)]
    for index in range(len(s) - 3, 0, -3):
        s.insert(index, ',')
    return ''.join(s)
```

## Test

```
>>> format_number(1123456789)
'1,123,456,789'
>>> format_number(6789)
'6,789'
>>> format_number(135)
'135'
```

## If `range`, `list.insert` and `str.join` are not allowed

We can replace

- `range` with `while` loop,
- `list.insert` using slicing and concatenation,
- `str.join` with concatenation,

like

```
def format_number(number):
    s = [x for x in str(number)]
    index = len(s) - 3
    while index > 0:
        s = s[:index] + [','] + s[index:]
        index -= 3
    result = ''
    for character in s:
        result += character
    return result
```

## Using `str.format`

Finally, following [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

> The ',' option signals the use of a comma for a thousands separator. For a locale aware separator, use the 'n' integer presentation type instead.

your function can be simplified to

```
def format_number(number):
    return '{:,}'.format(number)
```

and it will even work for `float`s.