# How to convert numbers to string with decimal and commas

Tags: python

I'd like to convert a number like 1323.67 to 1.323,67, how can I do that?

I've tried this

`f'{1325.76:.,2f}'`

but it prints out 1,325.76

I excpected `f'{1325.76:.,2f}'` to be 1.325,75 but it's 1,325.76

Comment: requirement does not seems to appropriate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print number with commas as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators)

Answer (score 5):

If you can use external modules, I would suggest you to use `babel`

```
>>> from babel.numbers import format_decimal
>>> format_decimal(1323.67, locale='de_DE')
'1.323,67'
```

Comment: Instead of introducing another dependence, we can just correct the f-formatting

Comment: I like this despite the dependency because it makes the intent clear. I couldn't understand why the OP has such a strange formatting requirement but it turns out, it's a thing of a specific locale.

Answer (score 1):

The format is

`f'{1325.76:,.2f}'` and not
`f'{1325.76:.,2f}'`

`:,.2f` is what you want. Which means `,` as separator with 2 decimal positions.