# Django: How do I show formatted number with thousands separator correctly?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to show formatted number with thousands separator like '123,456,789', but with below code it doesn't show as desired at html. How should I correct this?
The below does work but it shows like '123456789 EUR'

views.py

```
class ScatterView(TemplateView) :
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['price'] = str(plots.get_price()).format()
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
{{ price }} EUR
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in [humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/humanize/) package.

This package has several features to format numbers, dates etc. in human readable format. The one you want is the intcomma function.

Simply add `'django.contrib.humanize'` to you `INSTALLED_APPS`, load the template tags in your template with `{% load humanize %}`, and use it like this:

```
{{ price | intcomma }} EUR
```

123456789 EUR will be changed to 123,456,789 EUR