# ipython or pycharm underscore thousand separator in numeric literals

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, ipython

I am using pycharm with ipython enabled in debugger.
 How can I get nuumeric literals to be displayed/printed with underscode as a thousands separator.
Instead of this 107010000 I need 107_010_000. 
Please refer to the screenshot where I marked places I want such formatting to be applied.
I already seen this post:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004398280-DataGrip-2019-2-1-showing-underscore-for-thousands-separator-in-editor

**Update:**
And I have seen [How to print number with commas as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators)
My question is not how to format numeric literal using python programming language. It is about representation in ipython or pycharm debugger. I need this by default. 
For instance if I do this:

```
a = 1000
print(a)
```

I want to see:

```
1_000
```

[image]

Comment: As for inline values, there's no such option in PyCharm, unfortunately.
And as for ipython, you could write your own print function or even overwrite the build-in one, but I don't think there's a way to avoid formatting using python.