# Regex add comma separator in number

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to add comma separator to number string.

```py
import re

s = '12 123 1234 12345 123456 1234567 12345678'
print(re.sub(r'(\d{3}\b)', r',\1', s))

# gives
# 12 ,123 1,234 12,345 123,456 12345,678
```

where:

- 123 should'nt have comma
- 1234567 should be 1,234,567
- 12345678 should be 12345,678

Comment: Is there a limit to the size of the numbers?

Comment: 0-16 digit number will do

Comment: How about using string format? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators

Comment: @hylowaker ohh thanks!

Comment: Why should `12345678` be `12345,678`? Surely it should be `12,345,678`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using `re`:

```
s = '12 123 1234 12345 123456 1234567 12345678 00111222333444555666'
s2 = ''
while s != s2:
    s2 = s
    s = re.sub(r'(\d)(\d{3}\b)', r'\1,\2', s2)
print(s)
```

prints

```
12 123 1,234 12,345 123,456 1,234,567 12,345,678 00,111,222,333,444,555,666
```