# How can I format the plt.axhline label with a thousand separator?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, text, bar-chart

This is what my bar chart looks like ..

[![mychart][1]][1]

I wish I could format the axhline text with a thousand separator. Is there a way to do this?
I have looked  at FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: "[%.2f]" % x) so I wonder if I could do it within plt.text somehow?

my code for the axhline:

```
yline = plt.axhline(y, zorder=0, color='indigo')
ytext = plt.text(1995.05, y, 'y = %d' %y, bbox=dict(fc='white',ec='red'))
```

I have tried as

```
y_text = plt.text(1995.05, y,'{:,.2f}'.format(y), bbox=dict(fc='white',ec='red'))
```

and this does not work.

```
y_text = plt.text(1995.05, y, f'{y:,%d}') 

---> 53 ytext = plt.text(1995.05, y, f'{y:,%d}', bbox=dict(fc='white',ec='darkviolet'))
     54 
     55 
ValueError: Invalid format specifier.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/puKDC.jpg
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print number with commas as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators)

Comment: No, it does not. I edited the question.

Comment: It still does not work, Jordan.  ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float' for plt.text(1995.05, y, f'{y:,d}').
however, plt.text(1995.05, y, 'y = %d' %y) is not causing any error.

Comment: If `y` is a float, you can use `plt.text(..., ..., f'{y:,.0f}')`. In general, one gets much better answers if one creates some standalone test code.

Comment: y is just an arbitrary number I put in, like y= 40602. so, yes a float.

Comment: Yay, you're a star!  f'{y:,.0f}' works!  sorry if I sounded stupid. it is one of the coursera courses with no mentor and i'm learning.