# Confused on how to print numbers only from list and convert them into float

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

my code:-

```py
mean_distances = [td.text.strip() for td in rows[3].find_all('td') ]
```

Output:-

```
mean_distances: ['Mean distance from the Sun', 'km   AU', '57,909,175  
 0.38709893', '108,208,930   0.72333199', '149,597,890   1.00000011', '227,936,640   1.52366231', '778,412,010   5.20336301', '1,426,725,400  
 9.53707032', '2,870,972,200   19.19126393', '4,498,252,900   30.06896348']
```

I want to extract only the numbers in km (ignore the second number expressing the distance in AU) and covert the str data to float value.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
# loop over the items in mean_distances
# skip the first two rows which are the caption and column headers
for item in mean_distances[2:]:

    # split this item into km and au
    km, au = item.split()

    # remove commas from km
    km = km.replace(",", "")

    # convert km to float
    km = float(km)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float_value = [float(item.split()[1]) for item in mean_distances[2:]]
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the commas that are in all the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the items like `Mean distance from the Sun` and `km AU` will always take up exactly the first two items, you can use the `str.split()` method to cut off everything after the first space and the `float()` method to convert it to a float:

```py
temp = []
for distance in mean_distances[2:]:
    temp.append(float(distance.split(" ")[0].replace(",", "")))
mean_distances = temp
```

This gives an output of `[57909175.0, 108208930.0, 149597890.0, 227936640.0, 778412010.0, 1426725400.0, 2870972200.0, 4498252900.0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m=[]
for i in range(2,len(l)):
    m.append(l[i].split()[0])
    res=[float(i.replace(',', '')) for i in m]
  
>>> print(res)

[57909175.0, 108208930.0, 149597890.0, 227936640.0, 778412010.0, 1426725400.0, 2870972200.0, 4498252900.0]
```

If you want to keep ',' as thousands separators, to be more readable, see here for some solutions:

[How to print number with commas as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators)