# Can't add commas and also remove hanging zeros of big numbers in Python

Tags: python, formatting

I'm making a simple program where it calculates your average salary per year by just asking a couple questions. So when it calculates it I want it so it has commas and gets rid of hanging zeros.

```
calculation = (hourly_rate * hours) * 52
format = "{:,}".format(calculation)
format_2 = "{:2f}".format(float(calculation))
#Formatting big numbers to include commas
print("{0}, your average salary for the {1} job, is ${2} per year."
.format(name, occupation, format_2))
```

The math is 13.65 * 32 * 52 = 22,713.6
But my output is: $22713.600000

What I want: $22,713.06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're missing a period. I've also simplified things a little:

```
calculation = (float(input(f"How many hours do you work in a typical week? ")) * float(input(f"Your hourly rate is: "))) * 52
print("Your average salary is ${:,.2f}".format(calculation))
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed the issue!

Comment: You're welcome. From what I could see :,.2f was the main culprit. The rest was just simplifying the code. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your second variable `format` is a python special word, try to call it `format_1`, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators)
should help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use round function to remove zeros

```
round(decimal,1) # 1 is number of digits you want to round off
```

And check this link for the commas - [Commas](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-add-commas-to-a-number-in-python#:%7E:text=Use%20str.,add%20commas%20to%20a%20number&text=format(number)%20with%20%22%7B,with%20commas%20added%20to%20number%20.)