# Get OS-wide Decimal and Thousands Separator Symbols in Python

Tags: python, operating-system

I have `the space` and `the comma` as thousands and decimal separator symbols respectively on my system. I need to get this information in Python. Thus, I thought that I should use `localeconv` command from `locale` module for that purpose. However, `localeconv` command gives me different results: `nothing` and `the point` as thousands and decimal separator symbols respectively.

So, my question is: how to get proper system-wide information (thousands and decimal separators symbols, in my case) by means of Python but without invoking any terminal (command prompt) commands (so as to say, without using `popen` and stuff like that)?

[image: OS-wide separators]
[image: Separators shown by Python]

Comment: Note sure if this is what you want, but you could get the system locale with `os`, eg: `os.popen('locale decimal_point').read()`

Comment: @RJAdriaansen, thank you for your comment. I know about a `popen` solution but thought that maybe there is another approach without invoking terminal commands. So as to say, a single piece of code that will work on all platforms (Linux, Windows, macOS, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

A bit belated, but you have to use *setlocale* method from the *locale* module first, I think.
As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getdefaultlocale):

> According to POSIX, a program which has not called setlocale(LC_ALL,
> "") runs using the portable 'C' locale. Calling setlocale(LC_ALL, "")
> lets it use the default locale as defined by the LANG variable.

Assuming Python 3:

```
import locale

def get_locale_settings(locale_name: str = "", only_fields: tuple = ("decimal_point", "thousands_sep")) -> dict:
    """Return a dict of locale params.
    
    :param str locale_name: Desired locale name, or empty string for OS default locale.
    :param tuple only_fields: Desired locale fields, or None for all fields.
    
    >>>get_locale_settings(locale_name="en_US.utf8", only_fields=("decimal_point", "thousands_sep"))
    {'decimal_point': '.', 'thousands_sep': ','}  
    """
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale_name)
    settings = locale.localeconv()
    if settings:
        if only_fields:
            settings = {field: value for field, value in settings.items() if field in only_fields}
    return settings


print(get_locale_settings())
```

*{'decimal_point': ',', 'thousands_sep': '\xa0'}*

You can also get all the settings for any desired locale with only_fields=None, say,

```
get_locale_settings(locale_name="ru_RU.utf8", only_fields=None)
```

*{'int_curr_symbol': 'RUB',
'currency_symbol': '₽',
'mon_decimal_point': ',',
'mon_thousands_sep': '\xa0',
'mon_grouping': [3, 0],
'positive_sign': '',
'negative_sign': '-',
'int_frac_digits': 2,
'frac_digits': 2,
'p_cs_precedes': 0,
'p_sep_by_space': 1,
'n_cs_precedes': 0,
'n_sep_by_space': 1,
'p_sign_posn': 1,
'n_sign_posn': 1,
'decimal_point': ',',
'thousands_sep': '\xa0',
'grouping': [3, 0]}*

If you need separators to format a number, it might be easier to just use f-string formatting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-a-number-using-commas-as-thousands-separators).