# Dividing a number into one hundredth

Tags: python, list, if-statement, numbers

My task:

Write a program that separates natural numbers into hundredths with commas (counting from the right).

The program accepts a natural number as input.

Conditions:

If the number is less than three characters, the program displays the text NO.

Sample program:

```
Initial data: 14875
Imprint: 14,875

Intial data: 148
Imprint: NO
```

Comment: As you wrote it's **your** task. What did you try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print number with commas as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators)

Answer (score 0):

`f"{numb:,}"` will do this for you in python3. No need to write your own function(s)/class(es).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by comma at hundredth place.
So, I'm answering for both possibilities.

```
num = 1487526645
num_str = str(num)
result = ''
counter = 0
for i in range(len(num_str) - 1, -1, -1):

    if len(num_str) <= 3:
        result = 'NO'
        break
    counter += 1
    result = num_str[i] + result
    if counter % 3 == 0:
        result = ',' + result

print(result)
```

will give you the output `1,487,526,645`.

and

```
num = 1487526645
num_str = str(num)
result = ''
counter = 0
for i in range(len(num_str) - 1, -1, -1):

    if len(num_str) <= 3:
        result = 'NO'
        break
    counter += 1
    result = num_str[i] + result
    if (counter % 3 == 0 and counter <= 3) or ((counter - 3) % 2 == 0 and counter > 3):
        result = ',' + result

print(result)
```

will give you the output `1,48,75,26,645`.

P.S.- As others will mention, it's a good practice to show your work before asking others for a solution. It shows your effort which everyone appreciates and encourages to help you.