# Commas between numbers in Python or Django

Tags: python, web

hi this is my code for Percentage for the price of a product:

```
def get_discounted_malile_price(self):
    result = int(self.price - (self.price * (self.discount / 100)))
    round_result = round(result, 3)
    return round_result
```

and this is my result:
[image]

i have add , for result number ,for example(1936000 -> 193.600.0)
I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10742904/17320013

```py
value = 123456789
print(f'{value:,}') # 123,456,789
```

If yes, your code should be

```py
def get_discounted_malile_price(self) -> str:
    result = int(self.price - (self.price * (self.discount / 100)))
    round_result = f'{round(result, 3):,}'
    return round_result # NOTE: it returns str type
```