# How to add or insert thousands commas in between digits of a number using Python?

Tags: python, number-formatting

I want to add or insert thousands commas in between digits of a number as long as I input digits like some calculators (see the image). For example, when I begin inputting the digits 793, the code inserts automatically a thousands comma if I input the forth digit say for example 5, hense the number looks like 7,935 and so forth. I have no idea, it seems difficult for me. You can show me with a variable, a text edit or anything else, and any help even small would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-a-number-using-commas-as-thousands-separators

Comment: Its hard to answer without seeing how values are entered. Do you have a minimal example? If digits are being entered, does that mean you are accumulating a string value? If so, you could convert that to an integer then use regular string formatting.

Comment: Do you mean when you're typing the input?

Comment: Yes, while I'm inputting or writing the digits of a number, just like in some calculators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you will have to somehow set an event trigger whenever there is a change in text block and upon receiving that trigger, update incoming text with the ones with added commas.

General python function that does the job would be something like this

```
def add_commas_to_num(curr_text):
    curr_text = curr_text.replace(',', '')
    output = ''
    for dig_no, letter in enumerate(curr_text[::-1]):
        output = letter + output
        if (dig_no+1)%3==0:
            output = ',' + output
    return output.strip(',')
```

edit : The two answers above are a lot better as they use python's inherent functionality. If you need to put it into function, it might look something like this

```
def add_commas_to_num(curr_text : str = '0'):
    curr_text = curr_text.strip().replace(',', '')
    return "{:,}".format(int(curr_text))
```

Comment: You understood what I meant. Your code is very nice but, the commas appear when I enter the third digit. I want it to insert commas "after" I enter the forth digit not "before". In short, commas don't appear until l enter the forth digit. I've tried some modifications to your code but useless. Can you help, please?

Comment: Thank you. It works. The second code is short and more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

You can format number on display like:

```
print(f"{your_number:,}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's built-in string formatting to achieve this. Here's how you can insert thousands commas into a number.

```
def format_number_with_commas(number):
    return "{:,}".format(number)

# Test
n = 1234567890
formatted_number = format_number_with_commas(n)
print(formatted_number)  # Output: 1,234,567,890
```

When you run the code above, it will print 1,234,567,890. The format() function with the :, format specifier adds commas as thousands separators.